# Problems with Java installation (making using Spark difficult)

Tags: java, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to get Spark running locally. When I launch it, I get the following error, suggesting something is weird with my java installation (or the path to it). This is on Mac OS Yosemite.

```
line 190: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_51/bin/java/bin/java/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

Any suggestions how to remedy this? Let me know if you need more info (I don't know where to start)

Edit: Clearly there is a setting wrong somewhere, I'm just not sure where. 
In my bash-profile, there is a line

```
JAVA_HOME=usr/bin/java
```

Also when I run java -version I get:

```
java version "1.8.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_40-b27)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.40-b25, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Can you share your spark-env.sh or any parameters you're passing to master?

Comment: Not passing any parameters in. To start it I have just been running 'IPYTHON_OPTS=notebook bin/pyspark'. 

I can't find spark-env.sh. I can only find a template for it (in conf) -- where should I be looking?

Comment: Solved! I created my own spark-env.sh and added "JAVA_HOME=<path to where java is on my comp>"

Comment: Share your solution for others to see, it's confusing for beginners that spark-env.sh is a template file.

Answer (score 1):

Solution: 
Something was weird with where Spark was looking for Java. Not sure how the default is set, but I found a way to override it.

1) In terminal run this and copy and paste the results. This gives you the path of your Java installation. 
$(dirname $(readlink $(which javac)))/java_home
2) In the spark-whatever/conf folder, make a file "spark-env.sh" and write "export JAVA_HOME="